# low speed after plotting figure

Tags: python, performance, plotly

I plot a figure using this code. After playing this cell the program became too much slow and it is very hard to zoom the picture.
How can I speed up this code?
(consider that this code is not completed and in the coming updates I will need for loop, so I can not replace it)

```
fig = go.Figure()

data=0
X=[]
Y=[]
for trial in range(len(frames_ts)):
    for data in range(len(frames_ts[trial])):
        new_y=original_output[trial][data];
        new_x = frames_ts[trial][data]/sampling_rate; 
        X.append(new_x);
        Y.append(new_y);
        data = data + 1;
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = X, y =Y, mode='markers', name='Real'))
```

Comment: What is the length of `X` or `Y`?

Comment: 155585
It is an electrophysiology data

Answer (score 1):

- given such a large data set, use `Scattergl()` instead of `Scatter()` as trace type
- below code shows this - after plotting interaction is ok

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

go.Figure(
    go.Scattergl(
        x=np.linspace(0, 100, 155585),
        y=np.sin(np.linspace(0, 100, 155585)),
        mode="markers",
        name="Real",
    )
)
```